# Why does negation comparison in IF statement invokes a method

Tags: java, if-statement, negation, method-invocation

I have following code

```
if ( !handleOptions(args) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( !initConfig() ) {
        logger.error("Error initializing configuration. Terminating");
        return false;
    }
```

And the code itself is self explaining until I noticed that there are no **else** statements and yet, methods handleOptions and initConfig are called and executed. How does that work? From what I know, the parameters of **if** clause (in this case) are either determined true and then exception is thrown, or, they are false in which case I would expect **else**, yet I dont see one and code is still executed.

Comment: Try debugging the code.

Comment: You have a confused understanding of what an `if` statement does.

Comment: "if clause (in this case) are either determined true and then exception is thrown, or [...]" *what*? No!

Comment: How does the code know whether `handleOptions()` is true or false ? The only way to know is to execute that method first before the if-statement gets its turn

Comment: Recommendation: Instead of returning false from a method in case of an error, consider throwing an exception. You are currently logging the string "Error initializing configuration. Terminating" which provides no information as to what went wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is called **first**, then its *return value* is tested to determine whether to go into the body of the block.

Another way to think of it is that this:

```
if ( !handleOptions(args) ) {
    return false;
}
```

is exactly like this, but without the variable:

```
boolean result = handleOptions(args);
if ( !result ) {
    return false;
}
```

If you think about it, it *has* to be that way; we can't know whether the result of calling the function matches a given condition without calling the function and getting its result.

---

> the parameters of if clause (in this case) are either determined true and then exception is thrown

`if` doesn't throw exceptions. (The expression being tested might, but `if` itself doesn't.)

> ..., or, they are false in which case I would expect else, yet I dont see one and code is still executed.

`else` is optional. If there isn't one, and the condition is false, it's just that nothing happens. :-)

Comment: ahhh, I see the fundamental mistake in my thinking, thanks for explaining. I will accept answer as soon as the timer goes out.